# Creating data base in lotus notes

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I am creating a new database in lotus notes programmatically. I am using the following code to create the database:

```
mailDBNAme          = m_LotesNotesSession.GetEnvironmentString("DefaultMailTemplate", true); 
m_NotesDatabase     = m_LotesNotesSession.GetDatabase("", mailDBNAme.Trim(), true);
m_NotesDatabaseNew  = m_NotesDatabase.CreateCopy("", p_strDestinationPath, 13369344);// 
m_NotesDatabaseNew.Title = "Converted NSF";
```

In the above code I am able to create database only upto 4GB and not more than that.
But I want to create large NSF files.

How can i do this?

Comment: as per the answer from rhsatrhs the last parameter should be omitted (indeed it should fail since it it greater than 4!). Also you should look using db.CreateFromTemplate instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running on Domino 5 or above, you should just be able to omit the maxsize parameter.
From the Domino Designer help:

> maxsize%
>
> Note This parameter is new with Release 5.
>
> Integer. Optional. The maximum size (in gigabytes) that you would like
>   to assign to the new database. This parameter applies only to Release
>   4 databases or those created on a server that has not been upgraded to
>   Release 5. Entering an integer greater than 4, generates a run-time
>   error that reads "Maximum size for database is 4 (gigabytes)," and the
>   script fails.